# Flask generator not streaming in Azure web app

Tags: python, azure, flask, streaming

I'm trying to send a JSON stream from a Flask web app to a browser.
Here's a reduced version of the server-side generator:

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
  def generate():
    for i in range(1000):
      time.sleep(0.05)
      yield '{"key": %d}' % i
  return Response(generate(), mimetype="application/json")
```

In the browser, I consume the stream with oboe.js:

```
stream = oboe('/stream')
  .on('node', {
    'key': function (scheme) {
       console.log(scheme);
    }
  })
```

Locally, in the development server this works very nice, the data is transmitted as a continuous stream. But when running this as an Azure web service, the GET request takes a long time and then gets all the data at once. It seems that the server does not stream any data until the generator is done.

Can this behavior be attributed to the WSGI/web server behind Flask that's being used on Azure? Is there any workaround besides changing the platform? Which WSGI server would support this kind of streaming?

Thanks for any help,

Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, it seems to be caused by IIS as the WSGI/Web server for Flask on Azure WebApp, but I'm not sure.

For which WSGI server support this kind of streaming, you can refer to the thread [HTTP Streaming with Apache mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424648/http-streaming-with-apache-mod-wsgi).

I suggest you can try to test the other `WSGI + Flask` combination server on Azure VM like Ubuntu VM server.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply and the link, Tornado sounds indeed very interesting. BEst, Boris